# Contact information in email templates

Tags: template, email, email-templates, order-email

Just realized that in order confirmation email it displays wrong hours to contact the store. Checked in `admin panel > system > configuration > sales > sales emails` and all templates files say default from locale. After finding *.phtml files in

```
/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order
```

I still `did not find a file to edit to change` the correct working hours to contact the store.

Another problem is that in **shipment confirmation email** the logo at t**he top of the email** does not display.

Comment: and what's the code used for the image display in the template? You can "preview template" in magento's admin, this should help you iodentify the problem, unless you're working on local email template files (.html)

Comment: Which version of Magento are you working with here, CE 1.7.0.2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer. The template files I was looking are were in
app/locale/en_US/template/email
however this only answers the first part of my question, as the code for the logo at the top of the page is the same.

Comment: What is the template code? If you change any wording, can you see the different email?

Comment: Yes, if you change the code it will display different. What I realized is that after checking the folder where email linked to the logo, logo was not there, I uploaded it via a FTP app and now the logo is displaying in all emails. To edit order related emails go to app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales